# [PANDAS]: How to Select a particular Column element corresponding to maximum of another Column element in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I am given the following dataset:

```
Country       Cold_drink_serving
India              54
Australia          64
Kenya              85
```

How do I Select the country with maximum cold_drink_serving in Pandas Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `idxmax` and `loc`

```
In [304]: df.loc[df.Cold_drink_serving.idxmax(), 'Country']
Out[304]: 'Kenya'
```